# react-router and webpack Code Splitting but error with Import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I use react-router 4+ to do the need to load, use import (), I have installed the required package

```

```
"babel-plugin-syntax-async-generators": "^6.13.0",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
```

```

.babelrc

```

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": false,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true,
      "moduleName": "babel-runtime"
    }],
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-decorators",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

```

But will be an error

```

```
unknown node of type "Import" with constructor "Node"
```

```

What should i do?